# Show a different QML file depending on whether the app has been authoarized or not

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Behavior: What I want to achieve is simple, When I open my application I will check `QSettings` and verify for a valid token, if i do have one, i will open my main window, otherwise i will open a authorization window.

Question: considering a `bool validToken = true`. how can I open my `qrc:/authorization.qml` passing to it some arguments, lets say an url for example? and if it is false, to open my `qrc:/main.qml` passing to it some different arguments, my profile for example.

What I have tried:
I tried to use`QQmlApplicationEngine::load()` to open different windows, but i was not able to load anything different than my `main.qml`.
I was thinking then, on using Loader in my `main.qml`. But I am still not very clear on how to do it.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you do your [settings in QML](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-settings-settings.html), it is perfectly doable, and actually much, much easier than using `QSettings` in C++.

Also, from the way you put it, it doesn't sound like you need two different windows, you just need one window that shows different stuff depending on whether you are authorized or not.

So you can have something as simple as this:

```
import QtQuick 2.8
import Qt.labs.settings 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
  id: main
  visible: true
  width: 1280
  height: 1024

  property bool isAuthorized: false

  Settings {
    property alias isAuthorized: main.isAuthorized
  }

  Loader {
    source: isAuthorized ? "AppView.qml" : "Authorize.qml"
  }
}
```

Basically, the `Settings` element will store whether your app has been authorized between different application runs, if you are authorized your app will show the app view, if not it will show the authorization view, where you can input some data and pass that to some C++ function that will do the authorization, and assign the returned value to `isAuthorized`.

Also, in order to get qml settings to work, you will have to fill in your app data in main.cpp:

```
  app.setOrganizationName("yourOrg");
  app.setOrganizationDomain("domain.org");
  app.setApplicationName("appName");
```

BTW consider that settings will not really be encrypted or obfuscated in any way, and it will be pretty straightforward to manually edit the setting to true from outside the application, so you might want to use something a little more sophisticated like say a hash string, which you can run some verification on rather than a simple true or false boolean.